# Identify the caller inside a method in Java

Tags: java

I have a class A and class B as below :

```
class A {
    public String myMethod(){
        // do-something
        return send();
    }

    public String send(){
        // sending for A;
    }
}

class B {
    public String myMethod(){
        // do-something
        return send();
    }

    public String send(){
        // sending for B;
    }
}
```

Now the `myMethod()` is same in both the class but the implementation for `send()` method is different for class A and B. I am trying to implement the myMethod() inside a Utility class to avoid the duplication of method logic.

```
class Util {
    public String myMethod(){
        // do-something
        return send();
    }
}
```

But while calling the send(), how would I identify which object actually calls the method so that I can redirect to the appropriate `send()`  method. Do I need the `instanceOf` in java or or what is a better approach for this problem.

Comment: On the whole, it's a design smell if code needs to care about who is calling it. This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you actually trying to do? Is there a reason that `A` and `B` can't implement a common interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative solution to **Anthony Raymond**:

```java
public interface Send {
    String send();
}

public class A implements Send {
    public String myMethod(){
        return Util.myMethod(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String send(){
        // sending for A;
    }
}

public class B implements Send {
    public String myMethod(){
        return Util.myMethod(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String send(){
        // sending for B;
    }
}

public final class Util {
    
    private Util() {}
    
    public static String myMethod(Send caller){
        // do-something
        return caller.send();
    }
}
```

---

Another solution is to use **Decorator Pattern**:

```java
public interface Send {
    String send();
}

public class SendDecorator implements Send {
    private final Send delegate;
    
    public SendDecorator(Send delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String send(){
        // do-something
        return delegate.send();
    }
}

public class A implements Send {

    @Override
    public String send(){
        // sending for A;
    }
}

public class B implements Send {

    @Override
    public String send(){
        // sending for B;
    }
}

Send A = new SendDecorator(new A());
Send B = new SendDecorator(new B());
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use inheritance to achieve this instead of extracting the generic method in a utility class that will need a parameter or reflection to identify the caller.

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    default public String myMethod() {
        // do-something
        return send();
    }

    public String send();
}
```

```
public class A implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String send() {
        // send for A
    }
}
```

```
public class B implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String send() {
        // send for B
    }
}
```

Using inheritance you can put the `myMethod` code in the interface and implement the `send` differently in child classes.

Comment: In Java 8+, you could also supply an interface with a default method implementation for `myMethod`, which is slightly better design (because, of course, you don't hold on to the single class inheritence slot, and instead implement a common interface)

Comment: `class A extends MyAbstractClass` -> `class A implements MyInterface`

Comment: @saka1029 Done, thanks for pointing this out :)